# For any real sequence $(\sum a_i)^2 + (\sum (-1)^ia_i)^2 \leq (n+2)\sum a_i^2$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

Show that for any real sequence $\{a_i\}^n_i=1$ we have the inequality:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^ia_i\right)^2 \leq (n+2)\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$$

**Proof Attempt**

First partition the indices into two groups $I,J$ such that $i\in I$ if $(-1)^i=1$ and $i \in J$ otherwise. Then we have that the LHS is:

$$\left(\sum_{i\in I} a_i + \sum_{i\in J} a_i\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{i\in I} a_i - \sum_{i\in J} a_i\right)^2$$

Apply the identity $(x+y)^2 + (x-y)^2 = 2x^2 + 2y^2$:

$$2\left(\sum_{i\in I} a_i \right)^2 + 2\left(\sum_{i\in J} a_i\right)^2 $$

Applying Jensen's inequality (or Cauchy-Schwarz) we have that:

$$\left(\sum_{i\in I} a_i \right)^2 \leq |I|\sum_{i\in I}a_i^2$$

and:

$$\left(\sum_{i\in J} a_i \right)^2 \leq |J|\sum_{i\in J}a_i^2$$

When $n$ is odd we have that $|I| = n/2+1/2$ and $|J| = n/2 - 1/2$.

When $n$ is even we have that $|I| = n/2$ and $|J| = n/2$.

Putting it together we have the upper bound:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^ia_i\right)^2 \leq (n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$$

Although I am missing an additional term $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$ since the desired inequality has $n+2$ rather than $n+1$ as I have.

Did I miss that somewhere?

Comment: In my opinion your proof is correct. The even case was asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83993/proving-2n-sum-i-12n-a-i2-geq-sum-i-12n-a-i2-sum-i-12?noredirect=1

Comment: The linked question proves a different inequality as far as I can tell, and that case is immediate from two applications of Cauchy-Schwarz. For large enough $n$, the inequality presented in this question is stronger than the linked inequality.

Comment: @MONADA43 The linked question show that when $n$ is even $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2 + \left(\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^ia_i\right)^2 \leq n\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$ which is stronger than yours  but it follows from your proof. If $n$ is even then $|I|=|J| = n/2$.

Comment: Ah I missed the summation index :) thanks!